# Find a derivative of equation that contains Fourier series

Tags: derivatives, fourier-series, functional-equations

I need to find a derivative of follow equation
$$
\left(r_{0} + \sum [a_{i}\cos(i\phi) + b_{i}\sin(i\phi)] \right)({\sin\phi-k\cos\phi}) - b = 0
$$

I know the derivative of $\left(r_{0} + \sum [a_{i}\cos(i\phi) + b_{i}\sin(i\phi)] \right)$. Let  this part is $X$ then I need to solve follow equation:

$$
(X({\sin\phi-k\cos\phi}) - b)' = 0
$$
$$
X' · ({\sin\phi-k\cos\phi}) + X · ({\cos\phi+k\sin\phi}) = 0
$$

Is that correct?

Comment: would it not be better to write the Fourier expansion in complex notation?

Comment: @Chinny84 No, I working with real numbers.